# Can LaTeX provide summary of all the places where I used a certain citation?

Tags: biblatex, citing

So my question is whether LaTeX can provide me with a summary of where I used a certain citation. Say I have used a certain citation "(Havenga, 2021)" 5 times in my LaTeX document. The `\citecount` function will be able to tell me that I have cited it 5 times in my document. But is there some function I can use that will tell me I have used Havenga (2021) in the following sections:

- Ch. 1, Sec. 2
- Ch. 2, Sec. 3
- Ch. 2, Sec. 5
- Ch. 4, Sec. 1
- Ch. 4, Sec. 2

Comment: The general idea of this is usually called back-reference (`backref`) in LaTeX. It is available in different shape and forms depending on your citation package. So the answer will depend on the citation package you load- You have used the tag `biblatex`, but you don't mention `biblatex` anywhere explicitly. Could you please show us a short example document of how you generate your citations?